# Above the fold screenshots using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver for screenshots, and now it is only giving me full site screenshots. How can I see just what is above the fold?

Current code:

```
driver = Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(:browser => :firefox, :agent => :iphone, :orientation => ;landscape)
browser = Watir::Browser.new driver
browser.goto "http://forefathersgroup.com"
browser.driver.save_screenshot "forefathers.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get only visible part of the page using watir-webdriver, because selenium, which is used in this library does not provide such functionality.

So one of possible solutions is crop a screenshot after its creation

Comment: Have you tried to use chrome instead of firefox? Looks like chromedriver2 captures only visible part - https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294

Comment: Yes. I have. I've been using Firefox for a number of reasons right now, and another thing is...I need both full screen shots and above the fold shots. On Firefox I have one, on chrome the other...